# Android Studio 1.4 on a Windows 10 64bit screens hang and become unresponsive

Tags: java, android

I have looked on stack overflow and can't find anything relating to my problem. If the solution to my problem is on stack overflow and I have overlooked by accident, sorry!

The installation and most of the install works very well with Android 1.4 on Windows 10 64bit. The AVD is ok and loads pretty quickly now after some tips found on this very site. 
Unfortunately whilst in the Android IDE problems occurs when launching menu options such as: File -> New -> Activity -> Blank Activity (Java submenu entry selected) and Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device, these screens just hang and become unresponsive. I have tried the compatibility options along with dpi setting. All path and java variables are set and correct(but would walk through again if someone has a fresh approach to this) Please could someone help it would be greatly appreciated.